# Do I really need to use MySQL Spatial Functions?

Tags: mysql, geolocation, spatial-index

Well I want your opinions about this case:

I need a database that will have... two or three tables at most, one of them will have points (latitude, longitude) and some other info.

It's really simple what I need: Get the points within a given radius.

I'm not asking how to do it (but any advice is more than welcome, **specially if it's about good practices**), I want to know if making use of the MySQL's spatial support would help. Since what I need is fairly easy to get with just one query, what I expect by using Spatial support is to increase **performance**.

So, are the spatial indexes going to help noticeably? I don't *think* the table will store that many points. I'd say no more than 200.

Comment: What's your main concern with using those functions?

Comment: It's just that I don't want to use them if I don't really need them. You know, we usually don't want to kill a fly with a cannon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's really only 200 points, I recommend you do without: This makes it much easier to write portable SQL (which I consider an important thing).

Write your SQL so, that first longitued and latitude are checked against the precalculated mins and maxes (giving you a rectangle), then check for the radius. This way, you will only need to calculate the radius without finally selecting the point for 1/pi of the result set.

I personally consider this an acceptable tradeof against writing SQL, that could if must be executed against SQlite or whatever.

Comment: Note that degrees of latitude change in size as you get closer to the poles. If you're dealing with locations in the far north or south (such as Alaska or southern Argentina), this may cause some significant inaccuracies.

Comment: That's what I meant by first checking against the min and max, then really calculating the radius: Near the poles you will get more "stage 1 false positives", but they will be ruled out by stage 2.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your point of view, Eugen. While I agree with you about the portable SQL being important, this won't be the case since we're sticking to MySQL and don't think that will ever change.